# Error creating UI component in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, google-ad-exchange

I'm trying to create a react-native UI component with google [Ad Exchange (AdX)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/android/quick-start).

However when the application is rendered no ads is displayed, when checking the android logcat I noticed the following message:

> W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(21182): Could not find generated
>   setter for class com.adx.AdxViewManager

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

For ease of understanding I put my code below how I am trying to develop this component.

***MainApplication.java***

```
package com.adx;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new AdxPackage()
      );
    }
  };
```

***AdxPackage.java***

```
package com.adx;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdxPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.<ViewManager>singletonList(
                new AdxViewManager()
        );
    }
}
```

***AdxViewManager.java***

```
package com.adx;

import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class AdxViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<AdView> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "AdxBanner";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected AdView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        AdView adView = new AdView(reactContext);
        return adView;
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adUnit")
    public void setAdUnit(AdView adView, String adUnit) {
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnit);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "size")
    public void setSize(AdView adView, String size) {

        Log.d(size, "setSize: ");

        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        Log.d("Adx", "createViewInstance: OK");
    }
}
```

***AdxBanner.js***

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";  
import { requireNativeComponent, View } from 'react-native';

var iface = { name: 'AdxBanner'}.propTypes =  { ...View.propTypes }

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('AdxBanner', iface);
```

***index.android.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AdxBanner from "./AdxBanner";
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Adx extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <AdxBanner
           size="BANNER"
           adUnit="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
           style={{height: 400, width: 400}}
         />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Adx', () => Adx);
```